# Is a holomorphic function analytic in a ‘real’ sense?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am taking a course in complex analysis, and I asked myself the following question:

> If a function $ f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ is holomorphic, can its real and imaginary parts be given by a power series in real variables $ x $ and $ y $?

The converse is false as $ (x,y) \mapsto x + y $ is real-analytic, but $ x + i y \mapsto x + y $ is not holomorphic by the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Hence, I would like to know if
$$
f(x + i y) = \sum_{p,q = 0}^{\infty} a_{p,q} x^{p} y^{q},
$$
where the $ a_{p,q} $’s are complex numbers (which can be split into real and imaginary parts to yield an answer to my question).

As $ \displaystyle f(x + i y) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n} (x + i y)^{n} $, an application of the Binomial Theorem yields
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\left[ a_{n} \sum_{q = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{q} x^{q} (i y)^{n - q} \right].
$$

Comment: Of course, there's no reason to think that the $a_n$ would all be real for a generic holomorphic function, right? Even if they were, you might consider writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nr^n\cos n\theta + i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nr^n\sin n\theta$$ (assuming the series is expanded around $z_0=0$).

Comment: @MPW right, I am looking only to expans the series for real variable. I was thinking about this idea but this does not lead to power series..

Comment: Formally, one has
$$
   f(x + i y)
= \sum_{p,q = 0}^{\infty} a_{p + q} i^{q} \binom{p + q}{p} x^{p} y^{q},
$$
which is easily obtained from the sum that you’ve written.

Comment: @Gato: Salut, Gato. Ma solution ne vous plaît pas?

Comment: @BerrickFillmore je n'ai pas eu le temps de regarder, il était 5h du matin.. Now I read it, too bad that I did not continue my attempt. Thanks +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, assume that $ f $ is entire. Then
\begin{align}
\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \quad
    f(x + i y)
& = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} a_{m} (x + i y)^{m} \\
& = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}
    \left[ a_{m} \sum_{n = 0}^{m} \binom{m}{n} x^{n} (i y)^{m - n} \right] \\
& = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}
    \left[ \sum_{n = 0}^{m} a_{m} i^{m - n} \binom{m}{n} x^{n} y^{m - n} \right]\\
& = \sum_{p,q = 0}^{\infty} a_{p + q} i^{q} \binom{p + q}{p} x^{p} y^{q}.
\end{align}
The transition from Line $ 3 $ to Line $ 4 $ in the derivation is justified because the sum in the last line is absolutely convergent, which in turn is true because
$$
\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \quad
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} |a_{m}| (|x| + |y|)^{m} < \infty.
$$

Comment: (+1): Particularly, the real and imaginary parts of $f$ are real-analytic, which is perhaps what the OP was getting at. :)

Comment: @user86418: Yes, I think that’s what Gato meant. I was too lazy to split the real and imaginary parts, but I think that he/she can easily infer that from the last line. Thanks anyway. :)